# PDO catch PDOException Error

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

It works great if the connection is valid, but it seems PDOException doesn't actually work if the connection fails. The catch totally fails to execute. If its fails, it break execution of this line `$this->dbh = new PDO("$db_driver:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);`. So i can't get PDOException in catch block. How do I keep get this to work?

```
<?php

namespace app\Helpers;

use \PDO;

/**
* Core class which exists only once through the application
*
*/
class Core
{
public $dbh; // handle of the db connexion
private static $instance;

// constructor to create a MySQLi instance (="MySQL Improved Extension")
private function __construct()
{

    $db_host = ConfigHelper::read('db.host');
    $db_name = ConfigHelper::read('db.basename');
    $db_user = ConfigHelper::read('db.user');
    $db_pass = ConfigHelper::read('db.password');
    $db_driver = ConfigHelper::read('db.driver');
    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO("$db_driver:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
    } catch (PDOException $pdoex) {
        exit("Database connection failed: " . $pdoex->getMessage());
        return false;
    }

}
/**
 * get instance of Core object
 *
 * @return Object self
 */
public static function getInstance()
{
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
        $object = __CLASS__;
        self::$instance = new $object;
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

}
```

Comment: echo `"$db_driver:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name"`; chk

Comment: You need to return the error. Remember that a class is a template (or a blueprint if you like). It doesn't do anything on its own. It must be instantiated.

Comment: @devpro its show, `mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxxxx`

Comment: @icecub but its not print `Database connection failed: blah blah....`

Comment: are u not entering the correct values?

Comment: Add `public $error;` to your class. Then instead of `exit()` do `$this->error = "Database connection failed: " . $pdoex->getMessage()); return $this->error;`

Comment: @devpro its perfectly works if connection is valid. if fails the connection its shows PDOException.

Comment: `$conn = new PDO("$db_driver:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", "dbuser", "dbpass");
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` try by using attribute

Comment: @devpro its not working.

Comment: than please share the errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a namespace issue.

When within a namespace, you have to address every root level class name by prepending it with a backslash.

But you didn't.

But the worst part is that **you should not catch a PDOException at all**. Just [leave it alone and let it report to a site-wide report handler](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#catch)

Comment: Doesn't the `use \PDO;` take care of that?

Comment: @jeroen, there is no PDO namespace actually. So  there is no `PDO\PDOException` neither

Comment: Makes sense, but how can `new PDO` work than with a valid connection? I would think that shouldn't work either.

Comment: @jeroen it surprized me too but I suppose that `use` can address a class as well as a namespace. So, adding `use \PDOException` should've worked too

Comment: @jeroen btw, one day I learned here on SO from Jack that pdo constructor will always throw an exception on error, and it is not affected by the error mode setting

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that! It says so in the manual but I always assumed that was depending on the error mode...